# How can I calculate the curvature of an extracted contour by opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I did use the `findcontours()` method to extract contour from the image, but I have no idea how to calculate the curvature from a set of contour points. Can somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: It would help enormously if you provide us with the list of things you have already tried and with a more specific question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me curvature is:

[image]

where `t` is the position inside the contour and `x(t)` resp. `y(t)` return the related `x` resp. `y` value. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization).

So, according to my definition of curvature, one can implement it this way:

```
std::vector< float > vecCurvature( vecContourPoints.size() );

cv::Point2f posOld, posOlder;
cv::Point2f f1stDerivative, f2ndDerivative;   
for (size_t i = 0; i < vecContourPoints.size(); i++ )
{
    const cv::Point2f& pos = vecContourPoints[i];

    if ( i == 0 ){ posOld = posOlder = pos; }

    f1stDerivative.x =   pos.x -        posOld.x;
    f1stDerivative.y =   pos.y -        posOld.y;
    f2ndDerivative.x = - pos.x + 2.0f * posOld.x - posOlder.x;
    f2ndDerivative.y = - pos.y + 2.0f * posOld.y - posOlder.y;

    float curvature2D = 0.0f;
    if ( std::abs(f2ndDerivative.x) > 10e-4 && std::abs(f2ndDerivative.y) > 10e-4 )
    {
        curvature2D = sqrt( std::abs( 
            pow( f2ndDerivative.y*f1stDerivative.x - f2ndDerivative.x*f1stDerivative.y, 2.0f ) / 
            pow( f2ndDerivative.x + f2ndDerivative.y, 3.0 ) ) );
    }
    
    vecCurvature[i] = curvature2D;
    
    posOlder = posOld;
    posOld = pos;
}
```

It works on non-closed pointlists as well. For closed contours, you may would like to change the boundary behavior (for the first iterations).

**UPDATE:**

Explanation for the derivatives:

A derivative for a continuous 1 dimensional function `f(t)` is:

[image]

But we are in a discrete space and have two discrete functions `f_x(t)` and `f_y(t)` where the smallest step for `t` is one.

[image]

The second derivative is the derivative of the first derivative:

[image]

Using the approximation of the first derivative, it yields to:

[image]

There are other approximations for the derivatives, if you google it, you will find a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But i don't understand why f1stDerivative.x and f2ndDerivative.x can calculate as the formule you show in the code?

Comment: There are several options for this. I add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: I have tried the code you post.But i got many value as -1.#IND000000000000?

Comment: That occures when both derivative values in the denominator are zero. I update the code. Now, there's an additional check and otherwise the curvature is zero.

Comment: But maybe the problem was, that the argument of sqrt has been negative. Added a `std::abs` call.

Answer (score 8):

While the theory behind Gombat's answer is correct, there are some errors in the code as well as in the formulae (the denominator `t+n-x` should be `t+n-t`). I have made several changes:

- use symmetric derivatives to get more precise locations of curvature maxima
- allow to use a step size for derivative calculation (can be used to reduce noise from noisy contours)
- works with closed contours

Fixes:
* return infinity as curvature if denominator is 0 (not 0)
* added square calculation in denominator
* correct checking for 0 divisor

```
std::vector<double> getCurvature(std::vector<cv::Point> const& vecContourPoints, int step)
{
  std::vector< double > vecCurvature( vecContourPoints.size() );

  if (vecContourPoints.size() < step)
    return vecCurvature;

  auto frontToBack = vecContourPoints.front() - vecContourPoints.back();
  std::cout << CONTENT_OF(frontToBack) << std::endl;
  bool isClosed = ((int)std::max(std::abs(frontToBack.x), std::abs(frontToBack.y))) <= 1;

  cv::Point2f pplus, pminus;
  cv::Point2f f1stDerivative, f2ndDerivative;
  for (int i = 0; i < vecContourPoints.size(); i++ )
  {
      const cv::Point2f& pos = vecContourPoints[i];

      int maxStep = step;
      if (!isClosed)
        {
          maxStep = std::min(std::min(step, i), (int)vecContourPoints.size()-1-i);
          if (maxStep == 0)
            {
              vecCurvature[i] = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
              continue;
            }
        }


      int iminus = i-maxStep;
      int iplus = i+maxStep;
      pminus = vecContourPoints[iminus < 0 ? iminus + vecContourPoints.size() : iminus];
      pplus = vecContourPoints[iplus > vecContourPoints.size() ? iplus - vecContourPoints.size() : iplus];


      f1stDerivative.x =   (pplus.x -        pminus.x) / (iplus-iminus);
      f1stDerivative.y =   (pplus.y -        pminus.y) / (iplus-iminus);
      f2ndDerivative.x = (pplus.x - 2*pos.x + pminus.x) / ((iplus-iminus)/2*(iplus-iminus)/2);
      f2ndDerivative.y = (pplus.y - 2*pos.y + pminus.y) / ((iplus-iminus)/2*(iplus-iminus)/2);

      double curvature2D;
      double divisor = f1stDerivative.x*f1stDerivative.x + f1stDerivative.y*f1stDerivative.y;
      if ( std::abs(divisor) > 10e-8 )
        {
          curvature2D =  std::abs(f2ndDerivative.y*f1stDerivative.x - f2ndDerivative.x*f1stDerivative.y) /
                pow(divisor, 3.0/2.0 )  ;
        }
      else
        {
          curvature2D = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        }

      vecCurvature[i] = curvature2D;


  }
  return vecCurvature;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python implementation mainly based on Philipp's C++ code. For those interested, more details on the derivation can be found in Chapter 10.4.2 of:

[Klette & Rosenfeld, 2004: Digital Geometry](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781558608610/digital-geometry)

```
def getCurvature(contour,stride=1):
 curvature=[]
 assert stride<len(contour),"stride must be shorther than length of contour"
 
 for i in range(len(contour)):
    
    before=i-stride+len(contour) if i-stride<0 else i-stride
    after=i+stride-len(contour) if i+stride>=len(contour) else i+stride
    
    f1x,f1y=(contour[after]-contour[before])/stride
    f2x,f2y=(contour[after]-2*contour[i]+contour[before])/stride**2
    denominator=(f1x**2+f1y**2)**3+1e-11
    
    curvature_at_i=np.sqrt(4*(f2y*f1x-f2x*f1y)**2/denominator) if denominator > 1e-12 else -1

    curvature.append(curvature_at_i)
    
return curvature
```